# Why do I get 'Database is already closed' when invoking StaticQuery updateNA "shutdown;"

Tags: scala, h2, slick

```
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver
import scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery

object Main extends App {
  val db = H2Driver.simple.Database forURL (url = s"jdbc:h2:mem:test", user = "sa", driver = "org.h2.Driver")
  StaticQuery updateNA "shutdown;" execute db.createSession()
}
```

Executing this with scala 2.11.5, h2 1.4.186 and slick 2.1.0 yields a "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database is already closed". What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing the "shutdown" prepared statement, the slick StatementInvoker asks the database for the updateCount of the statement.

The H2 database doesn't like being asked this because it's already shut down.

I don't know which of the two is not behaving correctly. However, if you happen to have the same problem, to close the database just use

db.createSession().createStatement() execute "shutdown;"